# Rewrite loops as a one-line loop

Tags: java

Is it possible to rewrite the following loops as one-line loops?

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
        if (points[i].equals(points[j])) {
            return "Two vertices coincide therefore a polygon can't be formed";
        }

    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
        if (points[i].isOnLineSegment(points[j], points[j + 1])) {
            return "There's a vertex on an edge therefore a polygon can't be formed";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write post conditions but besides possibly rewriting the loops each as a one-line I don't see how I could do this.

Comment: It seems like "I want to write post conditions" is your actual question and should be expanded on and clarified, otherwise this is an XY question where you are not actually asking what you want.

Comment: what do you mean by "one-line loop"?

Comment: @jhamon I'm not sure if the same concept exists in Java but in Python you can write single-line for loops.

Comment: I may be wrong, but in python doesn't that works only for simple loop? not for nested loops?

Comment: _"in Python you can write single-line for loops"_ Are you talking about [List Comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)? e.g. `[x for x in numbers if x < 100]`

Comment: @byxor Exactly, it seems I can't rewrite my loop. However, an answer below mentioned streams which I think would help me solve it.

Comment: @LLScheme Java doesn't have syntax as concise as python's list comprehensions, but yes, streams are the closest thing. If you're curious about the terminology, streams are used when writing loopy code in more of a "functional programming" style.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for :

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
        if (points[i].equals(points[j])) {
            return "Two vertices coincide therefore a polygon can't be formed";
        }
        if (points[i].isOnLineSegment(points[j], points[j + 1])) {
            return "There's a vertex on an edge therefore a polygon can't be formed";
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: as mentioned in the comment, your action here `points[j + 1]`, can thrown `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if no result is found, in this case, I would suggest to use :

```
if (j + 1 < points.length && points[i].isOnLineSegment(points[j], points[j + 1])) {
```

Comment: Note that `points[j + 1]` can throw an out of bounds exception since there is no check for it now.

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I'm looking for. Rather than converting the two loops to one, I would want to rewrite them as a literal one-line.

Comment: @LLScheme What do you mean "one line", please explain.  A loop with nothing inside of the body is already one line, how would you put anything in it with only one line total.  Unless you want to use streams or something.

Comment: @Nexevis, currently looking at streams, I think that solves my question thank you!